# Should function be continuous at point of inflection

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definition

I have some very fundamental doubts regarding **point of inflection**.

Should function be **continuous** at point of inflection.

Should **derivative exist** at point of inflection.

No book tells about these fundamental things but wax eloquent for differentiable functions on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

In order for a point of inflection to exist, the first derivative must reach an extremum at that point . But for the derivative to reach an extremum, the first derivative must exist in the first place, and in order for the first derivative to exist somewhere, the function must be continuous there as well.

Comment: Not true. Take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\-x^2&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $0$ is an inflection point of $f$, but $f''(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Dan Uznanski .So you mean to say that the function $y = \begin{cases} x^2 & x<0\\ \sqrt x & x\ge 0 \end{cases}$ does not have point of inflection at $x=0$

Comment: @josécarlossantos hm. I would not have called that an inflection point.

Comment: @DanUznanski But you should. $f'$ has local extreme at $0$, right?! The tangent line to the graph of $f$ crosses the graph at $(0,0)$, right?!

Comment: Upon further reading, Apparently I should. Okay, revising

Comment: I am however confident that the transition from horizontal to vertical described by @Maverick is not an inflection point; the tangent line (and first derivative) don't exist at the corner.

Comment: @DanUznanski I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the function must be differentiable (and therefore continuous) at the point of inflection. The point $x_0\in D_f$ is an inflection point of the function $f$ if $f'$ has a local extreme at $x_0$.

Comment: The definition that i have read was that $x=c$ is point of inflection if concavity of the curve changes about $x=c$. The definition doesn't mention any pre conditions

Comment: @Maverick It's just a matter of taste. The definition that I mentioned has my preference.

Comment: Very nicely put. 